HLS audio stream choppy in iOS and Mac Safari - but ok in Chrome, VLC
I have an HLS stream that seems to have the audio cut out and then return randomly. This only occurs on iOS devices, and Safari on Mac OS. It works fine on Desktop VLC, but not iOS VLC (as in, the audio never cuts out).
More confusing still - if we have multiple developers listening to the same HLS stream on different devices at the same time, we all hear the audio cut out and the return at the same time. So clearly something is wrong with the stream itself.
We create a dash stream from FFMPEG, and then create an HLS manifest in parallel.
   transcoder
            // Right now this is the max we'll get
            .audioBitrate('64k')
            // We only have 1 channel
            .audioChannels(1)
            // Enable experimental features ldash/lhls
            .outputOption('-strict', 'experimental')
            // Set url for syncing UTC timestamps with client
            .outputOption('-utc_timing_url', 'https://time.akamai.com/?iso')
            .outputOption('-write_prft', '1')
            // Streaming mode
            .outputOption('-streaming', '1')
            // Use segment file template so we dont list all segments in the manifest
            .outputOption('-use_template', '1')
            // Must be disabled for index_correction which is suggested for streaming use case
            .outputOption('-use_timeline', '0')
            // Fix up segment indexes if they drift due to bandwidth changes
            .outputOption('-index_correction', '1')
            //  Use 6 second segments, for live this shouldn't matter but this is Apple's suggested
            //  value for HLS
            .outputOption('-seg_duration', '6')
            // Push the frames out as fast as they come in
            .outputOption('-frag_type', 'every_frame')
            // Use mp4 segments
            .outputOption('-dash_segment_type', 'mp4')
            // Enabled low-latency mode
            .outputOption('-ldash', '1')
            // Output an HLS playlist too
            .outputOption('-hls_playlist', this.options.hlsEnabled ? '1' : '0')
            // HLS manifest name
            .outputOption('-hls_master_name', 'index.m3u8')
            // Use persistent HTTP connection
            .outputOption('-http_persistent', '1')
            // Do PUTs to the upload endpoint
            .outputOption('-method', 'PUT')
            // Dont let an output error hold up the stream
            .outputOption('-ignore_io_errors', '1')
            // Set a timeout for output
            .outputOption('-timeout', '1')
            // DASH format
            .format('dash');

Does anyone have any suggestions for what we should dig into next?

"So clearly something is wrong with the stream itself." - have you considered sharing the stream? I would cut down on using crystal balls.

thanks for the reply @MarkusSchumann - unfortunately the issue doesn't seem to happen if the audio isn't live. If we go back listen to the same part of the stream that cut out while live, it works on replay.
